# iOS simulator: How to specify window orientation on command line?

Tags: ios, command-line, orientation, simulator, device-orientation

I'm running the iOS simulator from the command line, and I have an app that is landscape-only. Unfortunately when I run this app in the simulator, it remains in portrait mode. Is there a way to specify the default orientation of an app when running the simulator from the command line?

Comment: Is it simulator or application window that remains in portrait mode ?